# Fetch system date from which GCP is opened in python program

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform

when I am using datetime.now in my python program running on GCP cluster it is picking up the cluster location date but I want my system date to be fetched. And I don't want to hardcode my timezone to convert cluster date to my local date.

```
now = datetime.now()
fmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
tz = pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata')
your_now = now.astimezone(tz)
print(your_now.strftime(fmt))
```

I don't want to hardcode timezone. I want my timezone to be fetched dynamically

Answer (score 0):

You can use the datetime package itself from python `>=3.0`, you'll get a `datetime.timezone` object:

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.utcnow().astimezone().tzinfo
```

For me the output is:

```
datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(0, 19800), 'IST')
```

Using `dateutil` to get local time:

```
from dateutil import tz
local_time = datetime.now(tz.gettz())
```

[pendulum](https://pendulum.eustace.io/docs/) will give you local timezone as well:

```
pendulum.datetime(2019, 11, 11, tz='local').timezone.name
```